# How to format argument in python

Tags: python, qgis

I am new to QGIS python programming but reasonably experienced in ESRI

I am trying to generate a raster with a constant value but the documentation, although laying out the arguments, I can't find examples of how to bracket etc. My code is:

```
import processing
processing.run(
    "qgis:createconstantrasterlayer",
    extent = [450000,450010,200000,200100],
    target_crs = 'default',
    pixel_size = '5',
    number = '2',
    output = 'X:/01_GISData/blah.tif'
)
```

with the error message as:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.10\apps\Python37\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
exec(code, self.locals)
File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: run() got an unexpected keyword argument 'extent'
```

Why is extent not liked? I have tried 'EXTENT', "EXTENT", EXTENT, 'extent' and "extent" with the same results in the QGIS documentation, uppercase is shown as the 'NAME', is it case sensitive?

Comment: What is `processing`?

Comment: Where's the documentation you mention? I looked on Google for `qgis processing run` but couldn't find an API reference.

Comment: From https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/279937, it looks like you're supposed to pass those things as a dictionary to the `params` argument.

Answer (score 0):

May be you should work through this [tutorial](https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/processing_algorithms_pyqgis.html) on using Processing algorithms in pyqgis. It explains how to construct the dictionary of parameters to pass to the `run` method in step 13.

Or if you are in a hurry look at this [introduction](https://anitagraser.com/pyqgis-101-introduction-to-qgis-python-programming-for-non-programmers/pyqgis-101-running-processing-tools/) which covers it on the first page.

Comment: Thanks, I did what I also do in the end. Look at the 'History' in QGIS or 'Export as Python' in ESRI to see the true construction